# How to open popup window after redirect Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How can I show pop-up window after redirect in Laravel with data?

Comment: Try and check this out: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/ a pretty nice solution you can integrate into Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [redirect with flashed session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data):

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('popup', 'open');
```

And then check if session data exists:

```
@if (session()->has('popup'))
    // Trigger JS or pass some trigger variable to open popup window.
```

Comment: So, I need to redirect only to controller, that shows views? Can I show view in this page?

Comment: Well yes, you redirect to come `Controller@action` which returns some view (you'll not be able to show popup without rendering some HTML and JS).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("YOUR MESSAGE")</script>';
```

put this in controller

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this. You need only use blade's templating!

```
//pass back a variable when redirecting
return Redirect::back()->with('error_code', 5);
```

And then in your blade template:

```
@if(!empty(Session::get('error_code')) && Session::get('error_code') 
 == 5)
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
@endif
```

This will create a script that opens the dialog whenever error_code is present and equals 5!